# "It is confirmed that"

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, sentence-patterns, sentence-meaning, complex-sentences

Can I write as below?

It is confirmed that,

1. The A requires B.
2. The C requires D.

(1.2. Are just random sentences..)

Comment: Why would it be incorrect? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Use a colon or ellipsis, not a comma. You need a continuing mark, if any, not a pause.

Comment: What are A and B? Nouns, propositions, clauses, letters...?